# Laplacians and Renormalization

Tags: fractals

Why is the renormalization factor of the Dirichlet form for the graph approximations of the Sierpinski gasket (5/3)^m?

Answer (score 1):

The renormalization factor of the Sierpinski gasket is derived in [Spectral Decimation Functions and Forbidden Eigen Values in the Graph of Level Sierpinski Triangles](http://ishitvtech.in/pdf/sajet-vol-12-no14-8.pdf). It depends on the contraction ratio of the construction, the number $\alpha=5/3$ is for a contraction ratio of $1/2$. I am not aware of a simple intuitive argument for why $\alpha$ has that value. Note that a contraction ratio of $1/3$ has $\alpha=15/7$ and a contraction ratio of $1/4$ has $\alpha=103/41$ --- so it seems unlikely that these numbers can be "guessed" without a calculation.

Comment: What calculation is done?

Comment: It's explained in the linked paper: you calculate an eigenvalue of the graph Laplacian.